# Create time series in R with weekly measurements for 30 years period

Tags: r, time-series, timeserieschart, trend

I have a set of weekly data for 30 years (1991 - 2020). The data was collected weekly between 5th may - 10 October every year. This gives me 23 weeks of data every year for 30 years.

I want to create a time series in R with this data.  How do I do that please? It should be just 690 entriesin the output, but it is generating 1531 entries in the output See my codes and data below:

I saw a similar question HERE, but mine repeats for 30 years.

```
myts <- ts(df$Kc_Kamble,  start = c(1991, 1), end = c(2020, 23),  frequency = 52)

Output in R:
Time Series:
Start = c(1991, 1) 
End = c(2020, 23) 
Frequency = 52
```

Sample data:

```
  Year  Week    Kc_Kamble
1991    1   0.357445197
1991    2   0.36902168
1991    3   0.383675947
1991    4   0.400703221
1991    5   0.418901921
1991    6   0.437049406
1991    7   0.453742803
1991    8   0.467291036
1991    9   0.475942834
1991    10  0.476898402
1991    11  0.464632341
1991    12  0.436298927
1991    13  0.396338825
1991    14  0.352731819
1991    15  0.313539638
1991    16  0.283932169
1991    17  0.2627343
1991    18  0.247373874
1991    19  0.235647483
1991    20  0.225655859
1991    21  0.216663659
1991    22  0.208550065
1991    23  0.203605036
1992    1   0.336754943
1992    2   0.334735193
1992    3   0.342654691
1992    4   0.363520428
1992    5   0.397733301
1992    6   0.4399758
1992    7   0.483592219
1992    8   0.521920773
1992    9   0.548597061
1992    10  0.560150059
1992    11  0.557210705
1992    12  0.542114151
1992    13  0.5173071
1992    14  0.485236257
1992    15  0.448348321
1992    16  0.409089999
1992    17  0.369907993
1992    18  0.333162073
1992    19  0.300014261
1992    20  0.270225988
1992    21  0.243406301
1992    22  0.219247646
1992    23  0.204966601
```

Comment: Well, a time series assumes equally spaced (in time) measurements... so I don't think you can get around having the dates you are not interested in (11-Oct thru 4-May) included in your series.

But... what is the purpose of your time series analysis? Perhaps you can achieve that goal without working with a time series per-se...?

(Also, please note that there is no link behind the word "HERE" in your text)

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to do a trend analysis on each variable in my dataset in R but it says I have to first create a timeseries of my data. I'm sorry I lost track of the similar post which I tried to reference here.

Comment: If you just want to do a trend analysis and you are not interested in analyzing seasonalities you could pretend all observations are contiguous in time and ignore the gap between October and May (as long as that makes sense in the analysis and doesn't disrupt your conclusions about trend). In practice, this means you define the time series with `frequency` 1 with no particular `start` and `end` dates. But if this doesn't convince you because you need to keep track of actual dates, you could go back to your initial setup and fill the missing period with ~ almost constant signal with some noise.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to do the analysis with the data but it required dates. That's why I asked the question. However, since I don't know much, I didn't realize I could alter frequency value to 1 and run it. I'll try this too and compare my answers with the answer I got from YLC. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me suggest the following steps to set up and start analyzing your time series.

1. **Initialize** your time series by creating a 'dates' sequence and 'data' (set to NA). Use the library xts to create the time series.

```
  library(xts)
  dates <- seq(as.Date("1991-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = "weeks")
  data  <- rep(NA, length(dates))
  myxts <- xts(x = data, order.by = dates)
  str(myxts); head(myxts); tail(myxts)
```

2. **Collect** your data.
   Data is collected weekly between 5th may - 10 October every year.
   Let's read the data and work with Weekly Total Precipitation for year 2014.

```
  ts_data <- read.table("https://www.dropbox.com/s/k2cxpja3cpsyoyc/ts_data.txt?dl=1", header =TRUE, sep="\t") 
  year.2014 <- ts_data[which(ts_data$Year == 2014),] 
  year.2014   # 23 rows of data for 2014.

  start <- as.Date("2014-5-5"); end <- as.Date("2014-10-10")
  collect <- which ( index(myxts) >= start & index(myxts) <= end )
  myxts[collect] <- year.2014$PRPtot 

  # year.2014 and collect must have the same number of rows
```

3. **Verify** the collected data. You should see data inside each time window, and NA outside the time windows.

```
  myxts2 <- window(myxts, start=start-50, end=end+50)
  str(myxts2);  myxts2
```

4. **Visualize** the collected data. You could view the complete time series (i.e. myxts). Note that autoplot drops all NAs.

```
  library(ggplot2)
  autoplot(myxts2, geom = "point")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you explain Step 2 further please? I don't know exactly where to include my data This code below imports my original dataset:

Comment: `ts_data <- read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/k2cxpja3cpsyoyc/ts_data.txt?dl=1", header =TRUE)`
  `ts_rainfall <- ts_data$pr_ptot #Weekly Total Precipitation`
  `ts_Tmin <- ts_data$tn_avg #Weekly average minimum temperature`
  `ts_Tmax <- ts_data$tn_avg #Weekly average maximum temperature`

Comment: You should have used 'read.table' instead of 'read.csv'. Note the data is tab separated, not comma separated. And also pay attention to capitalized headers. R makes a distinction.  I edited step 2 based on your comment.

Comment: Wow, this helped! Thanks a lot! I'm excited because this was very tough for me since I'm relatively new to R Now, I'll have to do the same for all 30 years. I also have to repeat it for all the other variables.

Comment: Glad I could help.  I am sure you can set up a simple loop to go through all the years. Consider a simple function to do that.